# Not recognising USB network adapter on 22.04

Tags: network-manager, 22.04

I am using a USB-C AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet network adapter with Ubunutu 22.04 on a Dell XPS. When I plug the adapter in it is not configured by NetworkManager. If I boot the laptop with it in place it works or if I suspend on resume it will configure it. It also works on Fedora. It looks like this;

```
sudo lshw -c network
...
*-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: f
       bus info: usb@2:3
       logical name: eth0
       serial: f8:e4:3b:5e:01:9f
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=ax88179_178a driverversion=5.15.0-27-generic duplex=half link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
```

After suspend / resume

```
    sudo lshw -c network
  ...
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: f
       bus info: usb@2:3
       logical name: enxf8e43b5e019f
       serial: f8:e4:3b:5e:01:9f
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ax88179_178a driverversion=5.15.0-27-generic duplex=full ip=192.168.1.125 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed`
```

Looking at logs it appears to be detected but not get past being renamed from eth0 to xxxxx

Seems like a bug to me?

Answer (score 0):

This was 7 months ago, but I had the same issue and found the solution.

```
sudo ifconfig [interface] up
```